# Error on ng add @angular/pwa

Tags: angular, progressive-web-apps, angular-service-worker

Iam trying to create a pwa app using angular.Initially I installed angular-cli 6.1 version but that version I think gives some error while creating pwa(related to ngsw.json already exists). So i added angular-cli 6.2.0-beta.2 and current ng -v shows

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.0-beta.2
Node: 8.11.3
OS: linux x64
Angular: 6.1.2
```

Now when i try to add ng add @angular/pwa it shows 'Could not find index file for the project'. Not sure why? Any help would be greatly favoured

Comment: Do you have index.html in your project? Can you show us your project structure?

Comment: I have src/index.html file. I have only done ng add project-name. No other chnages

Comment: what does `ng add project-name` mean? `ng add` is for adding a library to an existing project

Comment: sorry i mean i did only ng new project-name

Answer (score 0):

Delete `ngsw.json`  and all service worker files, and then re-add using `ng add @angular/pwa`. Make sure all the previous service worker files are gone, or start a new project.

Comment: Its brand new project, just after ng new project-name iam adding pwa files. There are no service worker files

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue and running the following code worked for me as I was missing project name:

> ng add @angular/pwa --project *project-name*